# Data Disappears from Column When I Add an Inner Join Statement

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, inner-join, sql

When I run this code:

```
SELECT * FROM Free_Cash_Flow AS C
```

I get this:

[image]

When I run this code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Free_Cash_Flow AS C 
INNER JOIN Quarterly_Growth_Rates AS G ON (C.Ticker = G.Ticker)
```

I get this:

[image]

**The problem is that when I add the `INNER JOIN` statement, my `Free_Cash_Flow` column returns empty.**

Additional Info

Here is the code I used to bind to the `DataGridView`:

```
con.Open()
Dim cmd3 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Free_Cash_Flow AS C", con)
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd3.ExecuteReader()
Dim da As New DataTable
da.Load(reader)
DataGridViewScreen.DataSource = da
reader.Close()
con.Close()
```

Here is the structure of the tables.  They are actaully saved queries that run calculations.  The fields `Growth_Rate` and `Free_Cash_Flow` are calculations.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you binding the results to the grid? (please add that code to your question)

Comment: @DStanley I have added the code for binding the results to the grid to my original post. Thanks!

Comment: What's the structure of both tables?

Comment: Is `Free_Cash_Flow` the name of a table and also the name of a *field* in that table (or another table)?

Comment: @HansUp Yes it is.  It is the name of a table and also the name of a field WITHIN that table.

Comment: Though I can't speak assuredly, I believe the issue is that both tables have a column named `Free_Cash_Flow` and I'm guessing that the column in the second table is empty for the result set and it's picking that one. This wouldn't happen in SQL Server, but I vaguely remember Access doing this.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Both tables do not contain a column named `Free_Cash_Flow`.  I have added the structure of the tables to my original post.  The table `Free_Cash_Flow` does contain a column named `Free_Cash_Flow`.  If this is a problem.  How do I fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: @HansUp Do you have any thoughts on how I might fix this problem?

Comment: I got confused by whether your tables are really tables or queries.  So I gave up.

Comment: @HansUp They are queries.

Comment: When you run your `INNER JOIN` query, which sources those two queries, *in the Access query designer* ... do you get non-Null values in the `C.Free_Cash_Flow` column?

Comment: @HansUp I the Free_Cash_Flow column is blank in Access Create Query in SQL View.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:-

```
SELECT
    c.ticker,
    c.year,
    c.period,
    c.free_cash_flow as freecashflow,
    g.qtr,
    g.growth_rate
FROM Free_Cash_Flow as c
INNER JOIN Quarterly_Growth_Rates as g on (c.Ticker = g.Ticker)
```

to alias the free_cash_flow column - in case it's the conflict in the name of the column and table that is confusing open office.  Add in any fields I've missed...

Comment: I tried this code `SELECT C.Ticker, C.Year, C.Period, C.Free_Cash_Flow AS FreeCashFlow, G.Ticker, G.Year, G.Qtr, G.Growth_Rate FROM Free_Cash_Flow AS C INNER JOIN Quarterly_Growth_Rates AS G ON (C.Ticker = G.Ticker)` per your answer and every column came back blank.

Comment: Where did you try this?  In Access?  In Open Access?  In your DataGrid?

Comment: I tried this from within my program.  Everything I do is from within my program.  I only use OpenOffice to view my database. Nothing else.  And I do not have access to Microsoft Access.

Comment: I think you need to be able to run your queries in Open Access to confirm they are returning what you want - and then move to why your programme isn't binding to the results correctly.  At the moment there are too many variables in the problem for someone to help.

Comment: @dav1dsmi1th I was mistaken.  When I tried your answer, not every column came back blank.  Only freecashflow did.

Answer (score 1):

I have been unable to recreate the issue under C# in Visual Studio 2010 when I leave the DataGridView completely on "auto-pilot". That is, I dropped a DataGridView onto the form and added the following code (in its entirety):

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var con = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;";
                con.Open();
                using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText =
                            "SELECT * FROM Free_Cash_Flow AS C";
                    OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    var da = new DataTable();
                    da.Load(rdr);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = da;
                    rdr.Close();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran that I got the following

[image: Test1.png]

Then I changed the query to

```csharp
cmd.CommandText =
        "SELECT * " +
        "FROM Free_Cash_Flow AS C " +
        "INNER JOIN Quarterly_Growth_Rates AS G ON (C.Ticker = G.Ticker)";
```

and when I ran the code again I got

[image: Test2.png]

Notice that the "Free_Cash_Flow" is not empty.

Notice also that the columns do not appear in the same order as they do in your screenshots. This suggests that there may have been some additional tweaking to your DataGridView (e.g., to re-order columns) that may have explicitly bound columns to specific field names or aliases.

You should carefully check the properties of your DataGridView to ensure that they match what the revised query (with the INNER JOIN) is providing. Apparently the fact that [Free_Cash_Flow] is both the name of a query and the name of a field is not an issue *per se*.

Comment: This may help.  If I substitute another saved query for `Free_Cash_Flow` everything works fine.  For example, I have a saved query named `Current_Ratio` and when I run this code `SELECT * FROM Current_Ratio AS C INNER JOIN Quarterly_Growth_Rates AS G ON (C.Ticker = G.Ticker)` I get data in all of my columns, including one named Current_Ratio.

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @gromit1 I might be inclined to add another `DataGridView` to the form, wire it up in place of the existing one, and see if Free_Cash_Flow is blank with the JOIN query. If not, then I'd compare the properties of each `DataGridView` to see why that might be.